# accessing the file in localhost from ajax jquery in react is not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

if i replace url in ajax by "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users" then it works perfectly but it is not working for localhost directory file "http://localhost/socialNetwork/hi.html"...and if i open the same link in on browser it also works..here is my simple code

```
componentDidMount() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost/socialNetwork/hi.html"
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("error")
            });
        }
```

it always says error....

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
componentDidMount() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/socialNetwork/hi.html"
            }).done(function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }).fail(function () {
                alert("error")
            });
        }
```

**update**
after your comment, it's because of CORS problem and there are solutions to handle it. if it's local you can simply handle it by

[Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: * in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

[CORS Everywhere in Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/)

and if you want handle it by [@Yusuf Kandemir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48419701/9260314)

> **PHP**
>
> `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`
>
> **.htaccess**
>
> `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/"`
>
> Change YOUR_PORT to your port which is generally 80.

**But I strongly recommend don't use this method because it causes some security issues on your live version on your websites.**

Comment: @ShuresNepali, you're welcome, fire up the browsers dev tools and check in the network section, what data this AJAX request sends and receives. please attach a snapshot of it in question.

Comment: @ShuresNepali what is your jquery version?

Comment: i am seeing in my browser dev tool that status:200, ,method:Get,file:hi.html,domain:localhost,cause:xhr,type:html,transferred:250byte,and size:11byte...that's all

Comment: console says something like this : Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/socialNetwork/hi.html. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

Comment: @ShuresNepali thank you for good information, I've updated my answer based o your feedback. hope works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is flagging as outside-origin. You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in php or in .htaccess file. If you add it in php page, it will only work for that specific page. If you add it in .htaccess file, it will work in every file including image, video etc. files.

**PHP**

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

**.htaccess**

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/"
```

Change YOUR_PORT to your port which is generally 80.

Comment: @zhilevan I can't comment on that answer. But I think he is working local only for now. And even if he moves all that to a server, no one can access from outside because it is restricted to accessible by  `http://localhost:YOUR_PORT/`. And he will not experience this issue on a normal server. This problem is only on localhost. Maybe if he makes API he will need that but only on API related pages.